# Finding the interval convergence power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I find the interval of convergence of this power series?

$\sum\frac{1x^k}{k^22^k}$

I performed the ratio test and did.

$\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2(2)^{k+1}}$*$\frac{k^2(2^k)}{x^k}$

Then I got
$k\rightarrow\infty$

$x\frac{k^2}{2(k+1)^2}$

$-1<\frac{1}{2}x<1$

$x=2$

$x=-2$

$\sum(-2)^k\frac{1}{k^2)(2)^k}$ converge becuase alternate series limit zero the converge.

$\sum\frac{2^k}{k^2(2)^k}$

But I am not sure if x=2 converge or diverge. I tried ratio and root they were inconclusive.

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$ that's an extremely well known result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $x = 2$, you have $$\sum \frac{2^k}{k^2(2^k)} = \sum \frac 1{k^2}$$

This series converges. Why?:

What do you know about the convergence of $\sum \dfrac 1{k^p}$, when $p\gt 1$?

Indeed, because this series converges, the series $$\sum \frac{(-2)^k}{k^22^k} = \sum\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^2}$$ thereby converges absolutely, so no need to use the alternating series test.

Comment: it converge p series greater than 1

Comment: Exactly, Fernando!

Comment: I see yes it makes sense because you took the absolute value the series converge then it absolute converge.

Comment: That's exactly correct.

Comment: @amWhy: Can use another UV +1

Answer (score 1):

The series converges for $x=2$. You may ask why...

Why not use the integral test, i.e. 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{1}^{n} x^{-2}\; dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 - \frac{1}{n} = 1$.